# Javascript Promise Chaining - Is it accepted?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I'm concerned about my code, although it is working.

As the title says, is it accepted? Because in my database, I need to fulfill Promise 1 before proceeding to Promise 2 because I need to access the variables and results of Promise 1.

So in-short what's happening in my database is this:

1. Insert in: user_tbl then
2. Insert in: login_tbl

Note that in login_tbl, there's a column that is a foreign key of user_tbl. So I have to finish inserting in user_tbl first, otherwise there will be an error.

By the way, I'm using postgresql, knex.js and bcrypt
Here's my code:

```
//This is the function that handles the signup
const handleSignup = (req, res, db, bcrypt) => {

const { employeeId, username, password, firstName, lastName, positionSelect } = req.body;

const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password);

if (!employeeId || !username || !password || !firstName || !lastName || !positionSelect) {
    res.json({
        haveEmpty: true
    })
}
else{
    db.transaction((trx) => {
        db.select('*').from('user').where('employee_id', '=', employeeId)
        .then(data => {
            if(!data[0]){
                db('user')
                .returning('*')
                .insert({
                    employee_id: employeeId,
                    username: username,
                    first_name: firstName,
                    last_name: lastName,
                    status: "Active",
                    position_id: positionSelect
                })
                .then(user =>{
                    db('login')
                    .returning('*')
                    .insert({
                        employee_id: employeeId,
                        username: username,
                        hash: hash
                    })
                    .then(login => {
                        if(login[0]){
                            res.json({
                                isSuccess: true
                            })
                        }else{
                            res.json({
                                isSuccess: false
                            })
                        }
                    })
                    .then(trx.commit)
                    .catch(trx.rollback);
                })
                .then(trx.commit)
                .catch(trx.rollback);
            }
            else {
                res.json('User already Exist!')
            }
        })
        .then(trx.commit)
        .catch(trx.rollback);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
}
```

Comment: You can use async/await to make more cleaner and easy to maintain

Comment: It's not accepted, it's **absolutely** advised. Promises were mainly born to avoid the [callback hell](https://www.google.com/search?q=callback+hell&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwic8qPGnIHhAhVFhqQKHYDpD7IQ_AUIDigB&biw=1852&bih=1065) problem, and that's exactly what you are having

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with chaining promises, they’re designed to work that way, _as long as you need to_. Just remember to avoid the common pitfalls (search for JavaScript promise hell, too many articles to pick one to link here).

Comment: You do not chain promises, you are immersed them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be inside the `.then(data => {` part. You're creating a new Promise there, but you don't return it to another chaining. I could happen, that this promise won't be resolved, because the wrapper promise makes no attempt to do it as it is not returned.

You can change your code as follows:

```
.then(data => {
    if(!data[0]){
        return db('user')
```

and

```
.then(user =>{
    return db('login')
```

If there is a promise created and not returned, the next `then` gets nothing:

```
Promise.resolve('abc')
    .then(res => { Promise.resolve(res.toUpperCase()); })
    .then(res => console.log(res) /*prints undefined*/);
```

The block `{ Promise.resolve(res.toUpperCase()); }` creates a Promise, but nothing is returned, it means the promise is not further chain and could not be resolved.

Everything is fine, when the promise is returned, the promise goes into the chain:

```
Promise.resolve('abc')
    .then(res => { return Promise.resolve(res.toUpperCase()); })
    .then(res => console.log(res) /*prints ABC*/);
```

The `.then(res => { return Promise.resolve(res.toUpperCase()); })` could be shorten as `.then(res => Promise.resolve(res.toUpperCase()))` in this case.

**EDIT:** some more promise chaining explanation.

Comment: In this case they are sometimes resolved. He use `then` / `catch` to feth data, but `commit` can be not resolved

Comment: @bato3 I'm kinda new in promises. So may I ask how `commit` can not be resolved?

Comment: @Ardi I'm mistake. They are resolved. (there are existential problems associated with a bad morning)

Comment: `then` function wraps a returned value into a promise, if the value is already a promise, will be flatted. `Promise.resolve(true).then(res => Promise.resolve(res))` is same as `Promise.resolve(true).then(res => res)`. I edit my answer for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To make it a chain, your code should look more like this:

```js
db.transaction((trx) => {
    return db.select('*').from('user').where('employee_id', '=', employeeId).then(data =>{
        if(data[0]) {
            res.json('User already Exist!')
            //if it's possible use `return` instead `else`
            return null;
        }
        return db('user')
            .returning('*')
            .insert({
                employee_id: employeeId,
                username: username,
                first_name: firstName,
                last_name: lastName,
                status: "Active",
                position_id: positionSelect
        }).then(user=>{
            return db('login')
                .returning('*')
                .insert({
                    employee_id: employeeId,
                    username: username,
                    hash: hash
                })
        }).then(login =>{
            if(login[0]){
                res.json({
                    isSuccess: true
                })
            }else{
                res.json({
                    isSuccess: false
                })
            }
            return true
        }).then(trx.commit)
        .catch(trx.rollback)
    })
}).catch(err=> {
    console.error(err)
    res.status(500).json({error: true})
})
```

And I recommend reading about Promises chaining, eg.this: https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Answer (score 0):

If promises is not dependent on each other? meaning you don't need the information from the first promise before you can fetch the second one, then yes you can chain them together.

```
const Promise1 = fetch('https://API_URL_1');
const Promise2 = fetch('https:/API_URL_2');

Promise
    .all([Promise1,Promise2])
    .then(responses => {
        return Promise.all(responses.map(res => res.json()))
    })
    .then(responses => {
      console.log(responses)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(error)
    })
```